# How to apply Scrolling Animations when user starts scrolling a content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to Add some animations to an element when it is in viewport.

```js
$(document).scroll(function(){
alert('How to animate with transitions left to right, top to bottom elements in my Structure ');
});
```

```css
.main-container{
width:900px;
height:100%;
overflow:auto;
background:#00496d;
color:#fff;
}
#section1,#section2,#section3,#section4,#section5,#section6{
width:100%;
height:300px;
border:1px solid #fff;
margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-container">
<div id="section1"></div>
<div id="section2"></div>
<div id="section3"></div>
<div id="section4"></div>
<div id="section5"></div>
<div id="section6"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I Need Some Real Time  Examples.

Comment: What sort of animation do you want to apply?

Comment: I need to Add different animations to different elements when it is came to viewport

Answer (score 0):

Try [Skrollr.js](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) for animation on scroll. Although this is not updated for quite a long time, but you might give it a shot based on your requirement. It matches your ask above.

Answer (score 0):

Try animation on scroll.
Download library of AOS ans add in your code. Here is the link where you can find library and also complete example how can use in your html class.
https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/